# Android change text properties of a view

Tags: android

How can I write a function so that it accept `TextView`, `Button` or `EditText`. I want to change the text properites. Do these has a base class so I can do like below, or do I have to write three different functions?

```
 void changeTextProperties(BaseClass view) {
        view.setText("text");
        view.setTextColor(color);
        //-- etc ..

    }
```

Comment: Button and EditText are extend TextView, so just use TextView

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the **View** type then cast View to type and finally change properties

```
void changeTextProperties(View view) 
{
    if(v.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.Button"))
    {
        Button b = (Button) v ;
        //Change properties
    }else if(v.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.EditText"))
    {
        EditText et = (EditText) v ;
        //Change properties
    }else if(v.getClass().getName().equalsIgnoreCase("android.widget.TextView"))
    {
        TextView tv = (TextView) v ;
        //Change properties
    }
}
```

Comment: comment by @rainash will do the job. thanks for the answer